# Isn't it: You look like "<object>"?

Tags: subjects

The Starbucks Rewards program has this tagline:

> You look like you'd love a free drink.

Is this grammatical? I couldn't quite understand how the clause "you'd love a free drink" act like an object. Or is this a phrase which means something like:

> You look like someone who would love a free drink.

?

Comment: It looks like you’ve misidentified *like* here.

Comment: I am confused. Is the tagline grammatical (according to modern English grammar)? Yes or no?

Comment: Yes. The latter.

Comment: Yes, it's grammatical, though informal for some speakers. "Like" is not a conjunction but a preposition here, with the content clause "you'd love a free drink" as its complement. Your paraphrase is just another way of saying the same thing.

Comment: Huh, why the downvote?